# mysql max between 2 columns of 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table with the same column in each

Can I create a query that will join the 2 tables and give me the max between the 2

I came up with

```
SELECT MAX(certificate_number) AS max FROM contacts_cstm
UNION
SELECT MAX(certificate_number) AS max FROM accounts_cstm
```

But this gives me the max value from each.  How can I modify this query to give me the max between the both of them

Thanks

Comment: I would be careful here. If you are using this query to find the max certificate number so that you can assign a new one for a new record, you are going to have really bad atomicity issues. If not, the answers below are just fine.

Comment: Yes I am assigning certificate numbers in php script

I already have an auto increment column for each table, what would you suggest be a better method for assigning new certificate numbers? Do you mean by atomicity issue that 2 users simultaneously creating accounts may in theory be assigned the same certificate number? What is another approach I could take for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Create another table to hold the current certificate number and use an atomic statement to retrieve and update the value. Here, I am not going to be much help, as I have not done this in MySql. The idea would be to UPDATE CertNumberMaster SET CurrValue = CurrValue + 1, then ask MySql for the previous value. In SQL Server, we have a stored procedure that does this: UPDATE CertNumberMaster SET @OutParam = CurrValue, CurrValue = CurrValue + 1. Since the statement is atomic, we get the previous value back and update the table at the same time. Note that CurrValue is the only column in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping with another query will do the trick:

```
SELECT MAX(certificate_number) AS max
FROM (
    SELECT certificate_number FROM contacts_cstm
    UNION
    SELECT certificate_number FROM accounts_cstm
) as CHILD
```

Comment: Simpler, but yours would be more efficient most likely. Mine will fetch ALL the rows from both tables, do the union filtering, THEN apply the max version. Yours would only fetch two child rows, then max those. It'd certainly mean less work with temp tables and whatnot.

Comment: In that case, I guess I'll undelete.

Answer (score 2):

Call `MAX()` outside of the `UNION`, rather than inside.

```
SELECT MAX(maxnum) AS maxnum FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(certificate_number) as maxnum FROM contacts_cstm
  UNION
  SELECT MAX(certificate_number) as maxnum FROM accounts_cstm
) subq
```

Comment: Worked fabulous!
All very good examples, this is the first one I tried. thanks

Comment: @user1019144 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark whichever answer you're satisfied with as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(m) FROM
    (SELECT MAX(certificate_number) as m FROM contacts_cstm
     UNION
     SELECT MAX(certificate_number) as m FROM accounts_cstm) t
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(certificate_number) FROM
    (SELECT certificate_number FROM contacts_cstm
     UNION
     SELECT certificate_number FROM accounts_cstm) t
```